# Find a way to change Node Version

Tags: node.js, angular-cli-v8

I have Node:13.5.0 version but it is not compatible with Angular CLI 8.3.21 version. So I want to get back to the Node 12. version.

Comment: You can use [nvm](http://nvm.sh). It makes it very convenient to switch between versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

> npm install -g n
>
> n 12.13.0

or if you're on windows you can try this : github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: what's wrong exactly ? what's your OS ? what's the input in your terminal ?

Comment: Well. Iam using windows OS and terminal is cmd.

Comment: I hope this could help https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to manage different versions.

- nodenv
- nvm
- nodebrew

I personally recommend nodenv because we can set up different versions for different directories (= different projects) easily.

Simple example (local)

```
cd /path/to/project
nodenv install <version>
nodenv local <version>
```

Simple example (global)

```
nodenv install <version>
nodenv global <version>
```

Comment: I am new to angular. So I have not heard these before.Thank you.I will try learning on these ways of managing different versions

Answer (score 1):

For Windows the straightforward solution is to go the Control Panel's uninstall page, uninstall Node.js, then get the install package from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ .

Comment: Thank you for yours reply!